# Can I use the Samsung Galaxy Ace for the apps I am creating?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in creating android applications, I want a cheap way to test my apps and saw the Samsung Galaxy Ace was fairly cheap. (This phone has been out for a while).

Would this be suffice as it has an older operating system installed. Some sites say they have Android 2.2(Froyo) and others Android 2.3 (Gingerbread).

Comment: You may want to accept an answer or suggest a better one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make sure at the very least that it has 2.3 but it will be just fine for testing apps. 
One of the issues the android community has though is older software versions. Android developers prefer to develop for devices on 4.0 - 4.2 because 4.0 has more features and the sooner the old gingerbread devices are no longer on the market and being developed for the less fragmentation there will be.

But again the answer to your question is yes

Comment: I would also like to add that using the emulator will help you also with screen sizes and the differences between API levels... but is a very good idea to test your apps on real devices :)

Answer (score 0):

There are still a lot of devices running Gingerbread and Froyo. It is usually good practice to ensure your applications run on older devices. You can always test (most of what you wish to test) using the emulator anyway.